# PyPDF2: how to add a footer to a pdf?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pypdf

In PyPDF2, how to add a footer to every page of a pdf file? Do I have to do something like

```
page5 = reader.pages[4]
page5.mediabox.right = page5.mediabox.right / 4
page5.mediabox.top = page5.mediabox.top / 4
writer.add_page(page5)
```

or is there a predefined footer function?

Comment: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/10/an-intro-to-pyfpdf-a-simple-python-pdf-generation-library/, tells you how to do a footer on each page

Comment: @chris it's using another library - I prefer to stick with pypdf2 if possible

Comment: @chris the thing is I googled before posting, and it was the only blog that i found about adding a footer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyPDF2 does not have a footer function.

You can add a footer by

1. Creating a single PDF page that only contains the footer, e.g. via reportlab
2. Adding that page as an overlay (or as a watermark) - see [docs](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/add-watermark.html)

Comment: accepting the answer just to close this question after 8 years. Obviously not going to test that since after 8 years I have forgotten what the issue is about